Nominatim 4.4.0 motorway_link not imported despite editing import.lua files
Hi I have nominatim installed on a ubuntu VM which I use for reverse geo-lookup. All is going well, but nominatim doesn't return the correct object when I do a reverse lookup for a highway entrance (motorway_link). For this import I have used https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/netherlands/flevoland-latest.osm.obf which is the smallest province of the netherlands. The import takes 30 minutes.
call:
[secret_url]/nominatim/reverse?format=geojson&lat=52.3976067014153&lon=5.348081447780394&adressdetails=1&zoom=17&namedetails=1

expected result
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "place_id": 10189945,
                "osm_type": "way",
                "osm_id": 6972708,
                "place_rank": 26,
                "category": "highway",
                "type": "motorway_link",
                "importance": 0.09999999999999998,
                "addresstype": "road",
                "name": "A6",
                "display_name": "A6, Almere, Flevoland, Nederland, 1336 ZG, Nederland",
                "address": {
                    "road": "A6",
                    "city": "Almere",
                    "state": "Flevoland",
                    "ISO3166-2-lvl4": "NL-FL",
                    "country": "Nederland",
                    "postcode": "1336 ZG",
                    "country_code": "nl"
                },
                "namedetails": {
                    "ref": "A6"
                }
            },
            "bbox": [
                5.3463977,
                52.3966557,
                5.3518242,
                52.4009178
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.348065750718098,
                    52.397617756544484
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

actual result
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "licence": "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://osm.org/copyright",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "place_id": 338896,
                "osm_type": "way",
                "osm_id": 261859776,
                "place_rank": 26,
                "category": "highway",
                "type": "motorway",
                "importance": 0.0533433333333333,
                "addresstype": "road",
                "name": "A6",
                "display_name": "A6, Almere, Flevoland, 1336 ZG, Nederland",
                "address": {
                    "road": "A6",
                    "city": "Almere",
                    "state": "Flevoland",
                    "ISO3166-2-lvl4": "NL-FL",
                    "postcode": "1336 ZG",
                    "country": "Nederland",
                    "country_code": "nl"
                },
                "namedetails": {
                    "ref": "A6",
                    "official_name": "A6"
                }
            },
            "bbox": [
                5.3447124,
                52.3981918,
                5.3504999,
                52.4004294
            ],
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    5.347445791083126,
                    52.39924864036557
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}


I have faced this issue in an earlier version of Nominatim (4.3.0). The solution there was to simply edit extratags-import.style file, go to the highway section and replace "motorway_link" : "main,with_name", with "motorway_link" : "main",
With nominatim 4.4.0 these import*.style files have changed to lua files. So I attempt the following:
flex.set_main_tags{
    building = 'fallback',
    emergency = 'always',
    healthcare = 'fallback',
    historic = 'always',
    military = 'always',
    natural = 'named',
    highway = {'always',
               street_lamp = 'named',
               traffic_signals = 'named',
               service = 'named',
               cycleway = 'named',
               path = 'named',
               footway = 'named',
               steps = 'named',
               bridleway = 'named',
               track = 'named'
               motorway_link = 'always',
               trunk_link = 'always',
               primary_link = 'always',
               secondary_link = 'always',
               tertiary_link = 'always'
              },

Yet still I don't get the desired result. Is there anyone that can help me?
